# Splitting by comma doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, file, while-loop

I Read some data from a text file, I am trying to iterate line by line and split by comma, and I ignore lines that starts with `#`, here is the text file content:

> #this is the simulation file for your exercise, please read it carefully.
>
> #every line that begins with a pound sign [now known as "the" hashtag (#)] is a comment line. you can automatically skip it.
>
> #here are a few examples.
>
> #there will be 5 categories : Comedy, Adventure, Educational, SciFi, Fantasy. 
>   #it is recommended that when you save in the main program, that you follow this convetion.
>   #the input syntax :
>   #id,book name,author,pages,yearofpublishing,category
>   CNV301,Treasure Island,Robert Louis Stevenson,304,1882,Adventure
>   8T88FF,Heir to The Empire,Timothy Zahn,416,1992,SciFi 
>   911MAR10,Plumbing for Dummies,Gene Hamilton,242,1999,Educational
>   6U754E,Berserk,Kenturo Miura,224,1989,Fantasy
>   7R011,The Troll Cookbook : Human Delights,Underchief Trogdor,7,-35,Educational
>   M140,Funny Cats,Jean-Claude Suarès,78,1995,Comedy
>   V269W7,Linus the Vegetarian T. rex,Robert Neubecker,40,2013,Adventure
>   UFF404,Algebra 3,Nebi Rogen,300,0,Educational
>   424242,The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy,Douglas Adams,224,1979,Comedy
>
> #add your own.  you can use sites like : http://www.generatedata.com/  to create quick lists.

Here my code:

```
  FILE* file = fopen(filepath, "r");
    char line[256] = "";
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
    if (!starts_with(line, "#") && !starts_with(line, " "))
    {
            if (line[0] == '#' || line[0] == '\n')
                continue;  // skip the rest of the loop and continue
            printf("%s", line);

            char* p;
            p = strtok(line, ",");
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                //printf("%s\n", p);  //<-- line*******
                p = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
     }
    }
        fclose(file);
```

where:

```
int starts_with(const char* line, const char* c)
{
    size_t lenpre = strlen(c),
        lenstr = strlen(line);
    return lenstr < lenpre ? 0 : strncmp(c, line, lenpre) == 0;
}
```

> 1. When I run the code and I prints the first line with some weird characters like: `∩╗┐#this is the simulation file for your exercise, please read it carefully.`
> 2. if I enables the commented line: `//<-- line*******`
>       I get error: "Access violation reading location", I only want to see the splitted values

Comment: I read :  !starts_with(line, "#") , it seems you don't want the line that starts with '#' but the function starts_with is not doing that.

Comment: @BobRun my output is all the lines that not start with `#`, as I want

Comment: You initialise line to be a constant string, and then read data into that memory location. That's not supposed to happen. Just initialise char line[256]; and then e.g. *line = '\0'; or memset(line, 0, sizeof line);